# My div with absolute position is affected by a clic of its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple custom dropdown with absolute position in its container parent, and when the parent is clicked it has to show the dropdown. the problem is that when I click on the child its calling the click method of its parent.

click on the green area (the parent).

```js
function clickHere() {

  if (document.getElementById("drop").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("drop").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("drop").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background:red; height:500px;">
  <div onclick="clickHere()" style="margin:auto;height: 40px; width:30%; background:green; position:relative;">
    <div id="drop" style="display:none;width:100%; height:200px; background:blue; position:absolute; top: 100%; margin:0;">
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: event propagation, a child is an element of the parent

Comment: do you have a solution for it?

Comment: add a click event to the child elements, and stop its propogation

Comment: https://medium.com/@vsvaibhav2016/event-bubbling-and-event-capturing-in-javascript-6ff38bec30e `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: thank you it is solved. why event propagation happens?

Comment: @WillyRosaHuanca https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-simplified-explanation-of-event-propagation-in-javascript-f9de7961a06e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the click event to the callback function. Then you can check for the `event.target` element and react to it, returning false to do nothing or proceeding with your code.

For the sake of this demonstration, I simply check if there is a click handler set on the element, but as you will probably have click handlers on the child elements later as well, you might want to check for  `event.target.tagName`, `event.target.id` a specific class name, or any other distinctive feature.

As suggested in the comments, another possibility is to register a listener on the child elements and then call `event.stopPropagation()`, but using this approach, one listener is sufficient.

```js
function clickHere(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (!event.target.onclick) return false;
  
  if (document.getElementById("drop").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("drop").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("drop").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background:red; height:500px;">
  <div onclick="clickHere(event)" style="margin:auto;height: 40px; width:30%; background:green; position:relative;">
    <div id="drop" style="display:none;width:100%; height:200px; background:blue; position:absolute; top: 100%; margin:0;">
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
      <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Hello</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change call to the handler to clickhere(event)

change the clickhere function to clickere(e) and add a call to e.stopPropagation() to the function.

Events bubble up the hierarchy by default.